# Does failing a MemtestCL test warrant returning my card?

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I just RMA'd my Asus 280x DirectCU II card because it would output no video.

RMA sent me back this card and it had a few minor artifacts when running BF4 so I suspected bad GDDR5 RAM. Here is the test but I have nothing to compare it to. I'm not sure if these errors are definitive prove that I should return this card.

**MemtestCL Results:**

```
Test summary:
-----------------------------------------
50 iterations over 2048 MiB of memory on device Tahiti
      Moving inversions (ones and zeros): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                 Memtest86 walking 8-bit: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              True walking zeros (8-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
               True walking ones (8-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              Moving inversions (random): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
             True walking zeros (32-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              True walking ones (32-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                           Random blocks: 50 failed iterations
                                         (52518052 total incorrect bits)
                     Memtest86 Modulo-20: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                           Integer logic: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                 Integer logic (4 loops): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
            Integer logic (local memory): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
   Integer logic (4 loops, local memory): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
Final error count: 50 test iterations with at least one error; 52518052 errors total

Press <enter> to quit.
```

**Update:
Test after using newer build of MemtestCL**

at https://github.com/ihaque/memtestCL (Download zip has compiled .exe already inside no need to compile)

---

```
Test summary:
-----------------------------------------
5 iterations over 2650 MiB of memory on device Tahiti
      Moving inversions (ones and zeros): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                 Memtest86 walking 8-bit: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              True walking zeros (8-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
               True walking ones (8-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              Moving inversions (random): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
             True walking zeros (32-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
              True walking ones (32-bit): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                           Random blocks: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                     Memtest86 Modulo-20: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                           Integer logic: 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
                 Integer logic (4 loops): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
            Integer logic (local memory): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
   Integer logic (4 loops, local memory): 0 failed iterations
                                         (0 total incorrect bits)
Final error count: 0 errors

Press <enter> to quit.
```

Comment: Sounds like it is a bad model of card....2 bad ones in a row.

Comment: Any errors indicates a problem. An error that happened every iteration indicates a problem

Comment: @Ramhound What I'm confused about is that I've read about GPU "soft errors". I can't find anything on what it means or if they're serious or as benign as floating point calculation errors.

Comment: Wait a second.  This doesn't look right.  I would expect at least some of the other tests to report incorrect bits too.  As it stands, only the *Random blocks* is failing.  Weird.  MemtestCL could be at fault here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am certain that the errors you're seeing are **false**.

The "random blocks" test looks flawed.  I would expect at least some of the other tests to fail as well, considering how badly the random blocks test fails.  Yet ALL the other tests pass with flying colors.

It would be a shame to RMA a card that is actually perfectly fine.

**UPDATE**

Check out [this forum post](https://community.amd.com/message/1280910#1280910) which is in relation to random blocks errors on Tahiti -- exactly the same as your issue:

> The problem seems to be a bug in memtestCL.exe...

It seems the Windows version is affected as well:

> Same test fails for me on Win7 x64 for both of my 6850s...

I don't know what version of MemtestCL you're running, but considering how little maintenance it's getting, I would put good $ on MemtestCL being at fault here and that your card is actually perfectly fine.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I updated my question with the correct updated MemtestCL version and it looks like you were right. Now it looks like I'll have to ask a separate question for my 3D artifact issues & BSOD when both my GPU and CPU are 100% load but not when they're at 100% by separately.

Comment: I had the same experience with the CUDA version, **MemtestG80**. **MemtestG80** reported random block errors on both of my GTX Titans, but **MemtestCL** found none.